# How parsing classfile in java?

Tags: java, apache, class, parsing, bcel

how can i parse class file in java ,,in this code,i parse current classfile calles bcel, but if i want to parse other classfile in other package for example (netbeans/src/filename.class),what should i do ?how can parse any class file by it's path? this code can apply only on the same (current class file),but i want a way to parse any class file by it's path ,can i do this and how??

```
   package bcel;

   public class bcel {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

   ClassParser parser=new 

   ClassParser(bcel.class.getResourceAsStream("/bcel/bcel.class"), "bcel.class");
  JavaClass javaClass=parser.parse(); }}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to parse any class file in any package,,not existing class .. for example : class file called filename in package called projects,,(projects/filename.class) ,,how can i do this??

Comment: The code that i wrote above work only for the current class ,,and doesn't work for any other path of other class file.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're even using the word "parse" correctly. Do oyu just want to load the content from a path?

Comment: Yes exactly,,i want to load content from a path ,,(using ClassParser)